# jQuery function to run on all on elements that have same classes or IDs that starts with same name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add classes to elements, so if clicked on some class that starts with same name, I like to run it on all the elements that have classes that starts with the same name, not only classes, also IDs.

This is where I am stuck now, I can not make it work:

```
$(".repair-" + (differentclass)").click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

I do not need a working code for the click function, I just have to know how I can approach this, so I can use it with different statements. Or maybe a different approach?

Comment: "*I am trying to add classes to elements*" - what classes? Added to what elements? Where's your HTML? "*if [I] clicked on some class that starts with same name, I like to run it on all the elements that have classes that starts with the same name*" - what 'name'? What is the "it" that you want to run?

Comment: @DavidThomas I already have my answer. Thank you for your worthless contribution.

Comment: Go check the reply again, I have updated it with explanation , a codepen  and a native JS solution. I do not think this was a badly asked question, I would call it short and concise.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like so:

```
$('*[class^="repair"]').click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

$ is the jQuery object. Everything withing the () is the arguments passed to the jQuery object.
You have to pass a string, so the argument start with either " or '.
* this selector simply means all elements. Then in the brackets, the class attribute is given to be "looked up".
The ^ is means "starting with", then you pass another sting value for whatever you are looking for.

Here is the vanilla JS version

```
var allTargets = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=repair]"); // QSA return a node list, you have to iterate through it to change things or add listeners
for (var i = 0; i < allTargets.length; i++) { // classic for loop will do
 allTargets[i].style.color= "blue";
}
```

As you can see, the other divs with similar class names remain unaffected.
Check out the codepen, I only have the plain and preferable vanilla JS solution on the pen.

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/rQPpGO?editors=1010

You could have the fadeIn and out functionality on top of that. I have that on another pen.

Comment: YOu are welcome, I will add an explanation what the above does and why, for potential future readers

Answer (score 2):

This is a scenario where you want to use event delegation using an attribute-matching CSS selector.

Assuming you already have a handle to the container that has these `repair-*` elements inside:

```
$container.on('click', '[class^="repair-"]', function(e) {
  // your callback here
});
```

Comment: Even though I have provided the other answer, I really like this one as well, very nice.